# Jenkins pipeline post build to run on a previously used agent workspace

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

In the Jenkins pipeline master-slave environment having multiple slaves type, how to force a post-build task to run in the same slave & workspace where a previous stage was executed.

For example, in the following pipeline code snippet, 3 different slaves are used. The "Dynamic Server Creation" stage is executed on "miscslave" type agent where we run a "vagrant up" command. The next 2 stages are executed in different slaves, 'performance_slave and 'seleniumslave'. Now when the tests are executed against the dynamic servers, we need to destroy it by running "vagrant destroy" as a post stage task. However, it needs to be run from the same slave "miscslave" workspace where the "vagrant up" executed, as it created a ".vagrant" directory there with the dynamic server machine info, which is required to run the "destroy".

How can we force the pipeline here to execute this post build task in the same workspace where "Dynamic Server Creation" was executed?

````
pipeline {
        agent { label 'miscslave' }
        stages {
            stage('Stage 1') { }            
            stage("DynamicServer Creation") {               
                agent {
                    label 'miscslave'
                }
                stages {
                    stage('DynamicServer Creation') {
                        //Create Dynamic server using vagrant up, create a .vagrant dir to save the create machine info
                    }
                    stage('DynamicServer Test') {
                        parallel {
                            stage("Execute Performance Tests") {                                
                                agent {  label 'performance_slave' }
                            }
                            stage("Execute UI Tests") {                                
                                agent { label 'seleniumslave' }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                post {
                    always {                        
                        //Delete the dynamic server using vagrant destroy. It has to be run in the same workspace where "vagrant up" was executed in "Dynamic Server creation stage"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Just an idea: In "DynamicServer Creation" save `NODE_NAME` to a global variable. In `post` create a node context using the saved node name, e. g. `script{ node(savedNodeName){ /* Delete the dynamic server... */ }}`.